# What should I do if the Indian immigration stamped the wrong visa on my Indian passport?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens

I returned to India from US today and at the New Delhi airport, the immigration officer stamped my arrival date on my expired Schengen visa instead of my current F1 US visa. The problem is that I noticed this issue after coming to Vadodara which is a 1.5 hour flight away from New Delhi.

Will this be a problem for me when I try to return to the US for my studies? If yes, what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why would Indian immigration stamp anything onto your US F-1 visa? Do you just mean the page they happen to have used was that one in particular?

Comment: @ZachLipton yes. I meant the page. When I arrive back to India, they put a stamp on my passport with the arrival date. The page that they put on the stamp happens to be next to my Schengen visa.

Comment: I can't see any reason why that would be a problem then. Most countries stamp any random page with space. If you need to prove you were in India, you can just point to the stamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should not be a problem. I don't see why the US would care about India's entry stamps.

Comment: When I leave from India the next time for US, can the Indian immigration ask me how did I enter India without an arrival stamp? And if I said that the stamp was at a different place, will they accept it?

Comment: @Limit Given that your arrival stamp is in your passport, I don't see why the officer would care precisely where it is in your passport.

Comment: I am just panicking then I guess